# filter by first 4 digits of a timestamp value in BigQuery standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a variable where the entries are date (timestamp). The exact format is like this: `2009-03-01 00:00:00 UTC`.

I want to filter all the rows where year is 2009 (first 4 digits of the timestamp). I am using google BigQuery standard SQL. I tried the following:

```
WHERE LEFT(CAST(incurred_month_timestamp as STING), '4') LIKE 2013
```

If anyone can share the query, it would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string functions on dates!  BigQuery has lots of useful date/time/timestamp functions.

The one you want is `extract()`:

```
where extract(year from incurred_month_timestamp) = 2013
```

Or use a range:

```
where incurred_month_timestamp >= timestamp('2013-01-01') and
      incurred_month_timestamp < timestamp('2014-01-01')
```

Comment: Thanks. The second option worked!! but, for the extract(), big quarry showed another parenthesis is required.

Comment: @MdMahmudulHasan . . . I'm not sure what parenthesis might be missing.  This works perfectly well:  `select extract(year from current_timestamp)`.  Are you sure you are using Standard SQL (you'll get an error with Legacy SQL)?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is using builtin `year` function in BigQuery Legacy SQL, which extracts the year from a timestamp.

Here is an example with your code.

```
where year(incurred_month_timestamp) == 2009
```

Comment: I think this looks simpler.